# JEditorPane with new line and concatenation

Tags: java, swing, newline, string-concatenation, jeditorpane

I am having an issue incorporating newline and text concatenation in `JEditorPane`.

I want to be able to take the text from two editor panes in my application and put it in another editor pane. But I also want it to take into account new line.

Generally to get the new line you have to set the editor pane to use HTML and then add:

```html
 <br>
```

That is fine and works.

However `JEditorPane.getText()` returns:

```html
<html>
...
</html>
```

Therefore when one tries to put 2 texts together you get:

```html
<html>
...
</html>
<html>
...
</html>
```

And the second text is not displayed.

Is there anyway to deal with this other than laboriously extracting the text from the HTML, concatenating it and then reinserting it into HTML?

Comment: *"Is there anyway to deal with this other than laboriously extracting the text from the HTML, concatenating it and then reinserting it into HTML?"* Yep. Use an HTML parser. This is what they were designed for, and they will provide a much more reliable & robust result than using `String` manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Andrew. I did consider using an HTML parser. However, that is the sort of laboriousness that I wanted to avoid. It is strange that something so basic would not simply be programmed into the component. Surely, many thousands of application or more require it and all would have to individually develop and test their own "wheel". Anyway, since my requirements are quite simple, the code below will be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found a solution.
I just used :

```
JEditorPane.getText().replaceAll("\n", "<br>")
```